# Как исправить ошибку в роутере?

Tags: node.js, express

Вот 2 роутера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 роутер сработал хорошо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если к 2 роутеру отправить любой запрос, то почему-то он придет к 1 роутеру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же почему то если я поверну местами роутеры, то они будут работать правильно

Comment: 1. Не знаком с express, но могу предположить что регистрировать роуты лучше в порядке обобщенности маршрута - сначала конкретные в конце общие. К примеру под маску "/" подходят любые адреса. Такая маска должна обрабатываться в самом конце.

Comment: 2. Адрес "/product/category/" не соответствует шаблону "/category", поэтому в любом случае обработается шаблоном "/"

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Можете поподробнее сказать по счет /product/category/ я что-то не понял